# Express ejs using a global object in template logic

Tags: express, ejs

I have a global variable which I'd like to use a conditional statement based on it's value.

Express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.isSpanish = req.isSpanish;
});
```

Template:

```
<% if (isSpanish == 'false') { %>
<p><span class="signUpTitle">Hunger Walk</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SIGN UP</p>
 <% } %>

<% if (isSpanish == 'true') { %>
<p><span class="signUpTitle">False</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SIGN UP</p>
 <% } %>
```

The global variable 'isSpanish' toggles between the string value of 'true' or 'false'. Is it possible to use this value in the template logic? If I log the value out to the console in my server.js file the value returns undefined; however, it appears to be present in the console when I check for it's value.

Comment: so the conditional statement in your template doesn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't work as it is.